# PETSC_VIEWER_DRAW_WORLD shows nothing

Tags: c, petsc

I just started with PETSC and I'm trying to plot a matrix using matView. My code is like:

```
 MatCreateSeqAIJWithArrays(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, nodes, nodes, rows, cols, values, net); //I want to visualize "net"

 //Visualization
    if(display >= 1){
        PetscPrintf(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, "CSR structure created.\n");
        MatView(*net,PETSC_VIEWER_DRAW_WORLD);
    }
```

When I use MatView this way:

```
MatView(*net,PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD);
```

I can see a list with the rows. But when I change it to

```
MatView(*net,PETSC_VIEWER_DRAW_WORLD);
```

nothing happens.

I can't see anything about net structure, not even the list.

I tried to run the examples but they don't work at all. Also, the PETSC documentation just makes things worse. Can someone help me? I don't want to see a list of rows, but the matrix (graphically).

---

More context from the comments:

- X windows is functioning properly -- was able to confirm with `gvim`, `xlogo`, `xeyes`, etc.
- Library has been rebuilt using `--with-x` option in `configure`. Still nothing appears.

Comment: Does the drawing routine require an X server? Are you able to run other X windows programs?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure of what is an X server... How can I check it? @chrisaycock

Comment: I tried to run "xinit":
"Server is already active for display 0
 If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
 and start again."

Comment: Make sure you have a `$DISPLAY` environment variable in your shell. If you have ssh'ed to a server from your desktop, make sure that you have X forwarding enabled. Try to run a graphical program, like `gvim`. You might also be able to run `xlogo` or `xeyes` if those are installed. We just want to ensure that you can run graphical programs before focusing on your code.

Comment: It's working for gvim, xlogo and xeyes. @chrisaycock

Comment: So X windows works correctly. And your `MatView()` function still displays nothing?

Comment: No. MatView only shows the list of rows when I use "STDOUT" instead of "DRAW" as mentioned above.

Comment: I found it "You create Draw windows or ViewerDraw windows or use options -ksp_monitor_lg_residualnorm or -snes_monitor_lg_residualnorm and the program seems to run OK but windows never open.
The libraries were compiled without support for X windows. Make sure that ./configure was run with the option --with-x" and tried to reconfigure my PETSC, but nothing changed. @chrisaycock

Comment: Did you run `make` and `make install` as well? Running `configure` will generate a new Makefile, but you'll have to rebuild the library from scratch.

Comment: Yes. Everything done and... I see nothing. @chrisaycock

Answer (score 1):

Try using "-draw_pause -1" as an argument to your PETSc program, if you're not doing it yet.

> -draw_pause    - Sets time (in seconds) that the program pauses after PetscDrawPause() has been called (0 is default, -1 implies until user input).